# MongoDB Compass slow Fetching Documents but fast query time

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-compass

Fetching documents takes 30 seconds which is too long but the explain plan Actual Query Execution Time (ms):1.
Database hosted in MongoDB Atlas free plan
Collection Size 8MB
840 Documents
Avg doc Size 60kb
3 indexes
I doubted a slow connection so I pinged the hosts (Connection info) but the server replies in only 23ms.
Mongodb Compass Version 1.37.0
This is important for me because it might help the slow loading in my actual software.I don't know how to proceed.

I tried restarting my pc.
I tried the explain plan but no info there.
I tried the compass connection Performance tab but got the error "isn't allowed in this atlas tier"
I am expecting a reasonable response time or an explanation.

Comment: How much data are you returning? Since you're on the free tier you could check to see if you've hit a their (such as network bandwidth) and are being throttled

Comment: MongoDB Compass returns 20 documents per page. The data size is 50mb which way under 500mb limit. Connections number never surpassed 50 at anytime and Data transfer never surpassed 1.5mb/s at anytime. I can't find if am being throttled by the server for the last two potential reasons. Ca, you help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Compass retrieves metadata like indexes, column information etc before fetching actual documents. This initial metadata retrieval makes the application slow. Another reason may be that Compass tries to load the entire collection upfront to show documents, so very large collections will load slowly.